# How to select data from the last 7 days of Table in Database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to perform a a query in PostgreSQL that be able to display the records from the last 7 days based on the Date field from a table in the Data Base, in my case the field is "fecha_reparto" and the table has the next structure:

| drv | value | fecha_reparto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 22/03/2021 |
| B | 2 | 21/03/2021 |
| C | 5 | 20/03/2021 |
| D | 6 | 15/03/2021 |
| E | 7 | 18/03/2021 |
| F | 11 | 17/03/2021 |
| G | 2 | 16/03/2021 |
| H | 1 | 19/03/2021 |

And I would like to get something like:

| drv | value | fecha_reparto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 22/03/2021 |
| B | 2 | 21/03/2021 |
| C | 5 | 20/03/2021 |
| H | 1 | 19/03/2021 |
| E | 7 | 18/03/2021 |
| F | 11 | 17/03/2021 |
| G | 2 | 16/03/2021 |

I tried to use Max() as follow but I got an error:

```
Select drv, value, MAX(fecha_reparto) from 
reporting_services.vw_mx_log_icaro_descripcion_entregas_comercial
WHERE fecha_reparto >= fecha_reparto - interval '7 days' and drv IS NOT NULL
```

After that I used the next one query, and I didn't get a error but i'm not pretty sure that it gives me what I want:

```
select drv,value,MAX(fecha_reparto) as fecha_reparto,
cobertura_3c_promedio from 
reporting_services.vw_mx_log_icaro_descripcion_entregas_comercial
WHERE fecha_reparto >= fecha_reparto - interval '7 days' and drv IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  drv, value
```

What do you think guys? It's okay with the last query or would I need something else?

Thanks by the way, best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you want the 7 day retention period to happen as compared to the most recent date in your table.  If so, we can use `MAX()` here as an analytic function to find this date, then use roughly your first query:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MAX(fecha_reparto) OVER() AS max_fecha_reparto
    FROM reporting_services.vw_mx_log_icaro_descripcion_entregas_comercial
)

SELECT drv, value, fecha_reparto
FROM cte
WHERE fecha_reparto >= max_fecha_reparto - INTERVAL '7 days' AND drv IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hi, Tim, thanks for answer, it seemed a great option, unfortunately is not working, I'll try again and if you have another option I'll be gratefull with you.

Comment: @Xkid `unfortunately is not working` ... _what_ exactly is not working?  The logic seems correct to me, based on my understanding of your original question.

Comment: It doesn't recognise the name of max_fecha_reparto I think is something with the MAX() function...the warning displays "max_fecha_reparto does not exist", any idea?

Comment: Oh...you need to run all the code I gave you as one transaction.  The error message you are seeing might happen if you are just running the select query without the CTE.

Comment: Sorry buddy! I was missing that, I'm a little bit tired haha but it worked! thanks a lot :D